# closing .NET application - object disposed exception

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception, object

I have this C# project... If I have a formdialog within the main form open and then click a button on that formdialog that exists the app, it closes and then crashes with the titular exception.  The message is "cannot access a disposed object" and it's in the main program.cs file.

After the formdialog closes, it begins processing the main form again, and runs this.Close().  If I do Application.Exit() instead, it doesn't crash but it also doesn't close, it just stays open, which I don't understand.

I didn't start having this problem until after adding some registry-related code but I don't remember exactly when nor do I understand how that could impact this.

My error is on the Application.Run() line here:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new GettingStarted());
    }
}
```

The main form is only to let the user find an sqlite database to open with the program.  Once they select one, it runs opendb() and proceeds into the next dialog form.  Once the dialog is over, it exits if the main form doesn't tell it to stay open.

```
    private void opendb(string path)
    {
        if (path == "") { return; }

        Registry.CurrentUser.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\JPro\\RecentDBPath", path);

        this.Hide(); MainJView j = new MainJView(path); j.Location = this.Location; j.ShowDialog();

        if (j.return2start == 1)
        {
            this.Location = j.Location; this.Show();
        }
        else if (j.return2start == 2)
        {
            this.Location = j.Location; this.Show(); 
            this.form_selectdb(null, null);
        }
        else
        {
            this.Close(); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: No.  I have no idea how to change forms once you've entered into the main one so whatever I'm doing is what I've figured out myself over the past day.  See updated post for more code

Comment: opendb is called in the "gettingstarted" form after the user browses for a database.  It then passes the path of the DB into opendb and then moves to the next form to open it and show the main program.

Answer (score 0):

you know this code block on this line

```
this.Hide(); MainJView j = new MainJView(path); j.Location = this.Location; j.ShowDialog();
```

and wait for the MainJView to close. What you want is open the MainJView form first. the in it's constructor you want to open the GettingStarted with .ShowDialog() and depending on the result you choose to close or proceed